# how to plot multiple columns in a graph inside tables in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to draw a graph inside a table in python?[image: the graph I want to draw]

Comment: There is a function to display a bar chart in the style of pandas. See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: You can also do [sparkline style plots](http://iiseymour.github.io/sparkline-nb/) inside jupyter notebooks.